# How to make route on OpenStreetMap using open layer 3 or 4?

Tags: javascript, c#, openlayers-3

I'm setting a route, not LineString, on the map, but there is no method I have found.

I'm creating route between two marker in the OSM map.

```
var route = new ol.Feature();
var coordinates = [[longitude, latitude], [Originlng, 
Originlat]];
var geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
route.setGeometry(geometry);
```

I expect the route should make like in Google maps.

Comment: You would need to use a third-party routing service such as Bing, HERE, Mapbox, MapQuest or Openrouteservice.  Here is some sample code using the Bing API https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298309/showing-route-between-two-points-in-openlayers-3/298526#298526

Comment: Mike which one is free ??

Comment: They can all be used free but unless you pay some will stop working if you exceed a monthly limit.